# rewrite rule for Everything but certain pattern

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want `http://my_domain.com/forum/index.php/blah_blah_blah` to not being redirected to anywhere.

But I want `http://my_domain.com/something_else_that_is_not_forum/blah_blah_blah` to be redirected to `http://my_domain.com/index.php/something_else_that_is_not_forum/blah_blah_blah`

So basically, only everything without `http://my_domain.com/forum/` prefix should be redirected.

I have this `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(?!forum.*)(.*)$ index.php/$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I think the regex should do exactly what I want, but in this case, seems that I'm wrong.
http://www.getnocms.com/forum/index.php?action=admin;area=manageboards;sa=newcat;df105e678e9b=e1a979a0631bd203b6794debc16ceced

Does anybody know how to do that correctly?

**EDIT:**
I use this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/forum 
    RewriteRule (?!^forum(?:/.*|)$)^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

That roughly say:
If request is not pointed to file or directory or symbolic link, and it is not `/forum` then
If it is not started with forum, then point to /index.php/url.

It seems to be logical (well, we don't need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/forum` actually), but it still failed when accessing this url: `http://www.getnocms.com/forum/index.php?action=admin;area=manageboards;sa=newcat;a5272d5=2fcf142818fc9df2aabb1364942a1d14`

Maybe rewrite rule doesn't work with semicolon? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are almost correct but some minor changes are needed. Replace your code with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule (?!^forum(?:/.*|)$)^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Very reasonable. Your rule seems to be logical. However, accessing this url: http://www.getnocms.com/forum/index.php?action=admin;area=manageboards;sa=newcat;a5272d5=2fcf142818fc9df2aabb1364942a1d14 seems to also be redirected into /index.php

Comment: I had actually posted this after testing it locally and I retested these rule with your URL and it still worked fine and didn't goto `/index.php` Are you sure this is the only code in your .htaccess and there is no other .htaccess in some other subdir?

Comment: I'm sure, I suspect there is a trouble with ";" character.
This is work http://www.getnocms.com/forum/index.php?action=admin&area=manageboards&sa=newcat&feb4219=bea74b1ac6aace220b204cb50a5d5027
while this is not: http://www.getnocms.com/forum/index.php?action=admin;area=manageboards;sa=newcat;feb4219=bea74b1ac6aace220b204cb50a5d5027

However I'll accept your answer as the most complete one, and maybe start a new question as the problem has been narrowed

Comment: I've make a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631786/is-rewritecond-doesnt-work-with-semicolon in case of you are interested to answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your accepting the answer, I will make an attempt to solve your new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule !^forum/ index.php/something_else_that_is_not_forum/blah_blah_blah
```

Anything that doesn't begin with...

Comment: I still need the url, so I guess I should do this:
RewriteRule !^forum/(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
But it still doesn't work

Comment: I've got something like this that works for me.

Try a few variants:

    RewriteRule !^/forum/; RewriteRule !^/forum

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum 
RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://domain.com/$1
```